Having issue on installing gazebo harmonic to ROS2 jazzy
I am having issue on installing gazebo into ros2-jazzy. When I try to install it by using the command;
sudo apt-get install ros-${ROS_DISTRO}-ros-gz
it says;
E: Unable to locate package ros-jazzy-ros-gz
Did I miss something before run the command, or something else? If anybody can help,
Thank you

Did  you run sudo apt update before running sudo apt-get install ros-${ROS_DISTRO}-ros-gz?

Hi, yes I did, thanks

Are you able to append details about the OS you are using, and the output from sudo apt update? Are there any failed retrievals?

Have you run the following command before trying to install ros-gz?
 sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture)] http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros2-latest.list'
 curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.asc | sudo apt-key add -
 sudo apt-get update


Hi, I tried the provided command, but it still does not work!, thanks
